# Yii2 forms with related AR's

Tags: php, yii2

For example I have AR **Item** and related AR **TranslatedItem**
One **Item** has many **TranslatedItem**

How I can render all of that in one form and how i can validate it?

I know about method `$form->field($item->translatedItem[$index], 'title');` but as for me it's hack.

And also, controller will look:

```
if ($item->load($_POST) && $item->validate) {
    foreach ($translations as $translation) {
        if ($translation->load($_POST[...]) && $translation->validate()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Symfony has such features, i know

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of working with tabular data:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/

You can also do it like you posted as you are close to the solution.